# How to subscribe to alfresco rss feed in ms outlook

Tags: outlook, rss, alfresco, alfresco-share

I tried to subscribe to rss feed in ms outlook. When I tried nothing is really happening. All I am getting is this.

[image]
[image]

When I click advanced or yes or no nothing is really happening

**EDIT 1**

I tried in lotus notes and I am getting

[image]

Comment: Does the feed work from other RSS readers? Does the `Advanced` button have anything useful within it?

Comment: Yes it is working in rss feed reader add in for chrome but it is not working in outlook.

Comment: Have you told Outlook your credentials for Alfresco? That 401 error makes it look like Outlook isn't authenticating you

Comment: Yes that may be it when I manually add the rss feed url in outlook I am getting you are not authorized. But how to provide the login credential in outlook

Comment: It's hacky, but what about if you put them in the url? eg `http://myusername:mypassword@myalfresco/alfresco/feedservice/....`

Comment: I tried adding them at the end of url it is not working will try add them in front

Comment: See [this server fault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/371918/76753) for the format required - username and password must come after the scheme, but before the hostname

Comment: Its not working I tried logging into internet explorer and added the rss sync settings in outlook. Now it is working